# Скачивание картинки по прямой ссылке

Tags: python-3.x

Необходимо скачать картинку и сохранить по прямой ссылке на нее с помощью python

Используется Python 3.5.

Comment: Где возникли затруднения? Добавте в вопрос фрагмент кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlretrieve
>>> urlretrieve('http://i.imgur.com/viibQ1r.jpg', 'C://users/user/desktop/lol.png')
('C://users/user/desktop/lol.png', <http.client.HTTPMessage object at 0x01BB6130>)
```

Или так:

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> with open('C://Users/User/Desktop/new_img.png', 'wb') as img:
...     img.write(urlopen('http://i.imgur.com/viibQ1r.jpg').read())
```

Comment: Использовал первый метод , все сработало